# Having trouble distributing a large association to sub-kernels

Tags: parallelization, associations

The following seems to work based on memory usage.

```
bigasc=AssociationThread[RandomInteger[10^30,10^6],Range[10^6]];
DistributeDefinitions[bigasc];
k=RandomInteger[10^30];
bigasc[k]//AbsoluteTiming
```

gives

```
out[101]= {9.37986*10^-6,Missing[KeyAbsent,754081007229273563874471056283]}
```

but
    ParallelEvaluate[bigasc[k],DistributedContexts->None]//AbsoluteTiming
gives

```
out[102]= {1.43257,{Missing[KeyAbsent,754081007229273563874471056283],Missing[KeyAbsent,754081007229273563874471056283]}}
```

This seems to indicate that the entire association is passed by ParallelEvaluate even though it has attribute HoldFirst.  Is there a way to properly use a distributed association so that the lookup takes place on the subkernels?

Comment: One should use  SetDelayed  instead of Set for the definitions of bigasc and k. And both bigasc and k should be distribute defined.

Comment: In my case I cannot do this. With SetDelayed the definition of bigasc would be reevaluated at every access.  It takes several seconds to construct.